# Unity editor freezes when I try to debug my multi threaded app

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

Whenever I attach the debugger to unity editor, the editor simply freezes as soon as I press the run button.

On Receiving a packet from my server I try to run an async task which calls a static method on my 'screen' script that implements MonoBehavior

```
public override async Task RunImpl()
{
    LoginScreen.UpdateSrvText();
}
```

LoginScreen looks as follows

```
public class LoginScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static LoginScreen instance = null;

    public TextMeshProUGUI ServerResponseText;
    private NetworkClient Client;
    private static List<System.Action> actionQueuesUpdateFunc = new List<Action>();
    private volatile static bool noActionQueueToExecuteUpdateFunc = true;
    List<System.Action> actionCopiedQueueUpdateFunc = new List<System.Action>();

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Client = GlobalControl.Instance.NetworkingClient = new NetworkClient();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ProcessUpdateQueue();
    }

    public static void UpdateSrvText()
    {
        instance.UpdateSrc();
    }

    public void UpdateSrc()
    {
        ExecuteInUpdate(() =>
        {
            ServerResponseText.text = GlobalControl.Instance.LoginScreenServerText;
        });
    }

    public static void ExecuteInUpdate(System.Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        }

        lock (actionQueuesUpdateFunc)
        {
            actionQueuesUpdateFunc.Add(action);
            noActionQueueToExecuteUpdateFunc = false;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessUpdateQueue()
    {
        if (noActionQueueToExecuteUpdateFunc)
        {
            return;
        }

        actionCopiedQueueUpdateFunc.Clear();
        lock (actionQueuesUpdateFunc)
        {
            actionCopiedQueueUpdateFunc.AddRange(actionQueuesUpdateFunc);
            actionQueuesUpdateFunc.Clear();
            noActionQueueToExecuteUpdateFunc = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < actionCopiedQueueUpdateFunc.Count; i++)
        {
            actionCopiedQueueUpdateFunc[i].Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to attach the debugger after I start the app, but then visual studio freezes and the editor. I am trying to reuse the code I found in one of the more popular questions here about implementing simple queue to the main thread, and it is working except for the debugger.

Comment: Are you getting the desired result from your code when your debugger is not attached? Does everything seem to be working as intended?

Comment: The code is working but when I attack the debugger Unity editor freezes completely

Comment: What unity version are you using? Dotnet 4.6 support was experimental in 2017.x versions. It may well be an editor bug.

Comment: Its unity 2018.x, one of the newer versions